# Cant copy from a file to vector of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, copy

So I have a class called `CStudentEmploy` containing 3 variables.

I have another class class 
 `CAnalizeData:CStudentEmploy`

which contains a vector of pointers 
 `vector<CStudentEmploy*>m_vData;`

I also have istream operator :

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& str,CStudentEmploy& obj)
    {
        str >> obj.m_strName >> obj.m_strFacNum >> obj.m_iMinutes;
        return str;
    }
```

I want to fill this vector from a file in a way like this:

```
CAnalizeData(const string &strFileName) {
        ifstream ifile(strFileName.data());
        copy(istream_iterator<CStudentEmploy*>(ifile), istream_iterator<CStudentEmploy*>(), back_inserter(m_vData));
    }
```

This way works if I am trying to fill a vector of objects.

The error I get is :

Error   C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type '_Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I understand there is a problem with the iterator,but can't really fix it.Thanks.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <istream>
using namespace std;
class CStudentEmploy {
private:
    string m_strName;
    string m_strFacNum;
    int m_iMinutes;
public:
    CStudentEmploy() {
        m_strName = "Empty";
        m_strFacNum = "Empty";
        m_iMinutes = 0;
    }
    CStudentEmploy(string strname,string strfacnum,int minutes) {
        m_strName = strname;
        m_strFacNum = strfacnum;
        m_iMinutes = minutes;
    }
    CStudentEmploy(const CStudentEmploy &obj) {
        m_strName = obj.m_strName;
        m_strFacNum =obj.m_strFacNum;
        m_iMinutes =obj.m_iMinutes;
    }
    int get_m_iMinutes() {
        return m_iMinutes;
    }
    CStudentEmploy operator =(const CStudentEmploy &obj) {
        this->m_strName = obj.m_strName;
        this->m_strFacNum = obj.m_strFacNum;
        this->m_iMinutes = obj.m_iMinutes;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator <(const CStudentEmploy &obj)const {
        return m_iMinutes<obj.m_iMinutes;
    }
    CStudentEmploy operator +(const CStudentEmploy &obj) {
        this->m_iMinutes += obj.m_iMinutes;
        return *this;
    }
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& str, const CStudentEmploy &obj)
    {
        str << "\nIme: " << obj.m_strName<< "\nF Nomer: " << obj.m_strFacNum << "\nMinuti:" << obj.m_iMinutes << endl;
        return str;
    }

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& str,CStudentEmploy& obj)
    {
        str >> obj.m_strName >> obj.m_strFacNum >> obj.m_iMinutes;
        return str;
    }
};
class CAnalizeData:CStudentEmploy {
private:
    vector<CStudentEmploy*>m_vData;
public:
    CAnalizeData(const string &strFileName) {
        ifstream ifile(strFileName.data());
        copy(istream_iterator<CStudentEmploy*>(ifile), istream_iterator<CStudentEmploy*>(), back_inserter(m_vData));
    }
    void Write() {
        vector<CStudentEmploy*>::iterator it = m_vData.begin();
        while (it != m_vData.end())
        {
            cout << *it++;
        }
    }
    void Sort() {
        sort(m_vData.begin(), m_vData.end());
    }
    double calcMean() {
        double avg = 0;
        vector<CStudentEmploy*>::iterator it = m_vData.begin();
        for (it = m_vData.begin(); it != m_vData.end(); it++) {
            avg += (*it)->get_m_iMinutes();
        }
        cout << "Average minutes is:";
        return avg / m_vData.size();
    }
};
int main() {
    CAnalizeData AB("Test.txt");
    AB.Sort();
    AB.Write();
    cout << AB.calcMean();
    cout << endl;   system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] along with the full error message (usually there's more after including what type it thinks thinks like `_Ty` are).

Comment: One thing to note, whether or not my answer works, is that you're storing pointers that never get `delete`d. A better answer might be to just not use pointers, especially since your sort isn't going to work correctly, either, and there doesn't seem to be any reason to have them, as the objects don't live anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something with `std::transform`:

```
CAnalizeData(const string &strFileName) {
    ifstream ifile(strFileName.data());
    transform(istream_iterator<CStudentEmploy>(ifile),
      istream_iterator<CStudentEmploy>(), back_inserter(m_vData),
      [](const CStudentEmploy &e) { return new CStudentEmploy(e); });
}
```

Using `new` there, since I assume the object would have been created on the stack.

Comment: Ah, I see.  This is why the full error is needed. clang under repl.it shows that the problem is `operator>>` (it wants an object, but the code is trying to give it a pointer)... edit incoming